# Wordpress Child Theme override media queries

Tags: wordpress, themes, overriding, media

I have a wordpress child theme that I have a heap of responsive changes set to happen at 940px. The parent theme has been updated and no has alot more things that get triggered at 768. Is there a way I can mass override them instead of calling every single rule to do the override?

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your effort behind it?

Comment: I don't really have anything left to show at the moment.....  I am a little lost on what to do (a bit of a strange concept for me)
basically I have a heap of `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {` in the parent css, and I want to override alot of them to 940px if that makes sense